# Twilio - Inviting Users on a private channel by sending them remote notifications

Tags: ios, twilio

I am trying to implement Twilio SDK for IP Messaging, Video Conversations, Call and SMS. Twilio fits all the bills perfectly as far as the requirement is concerned. However, we are facing some challenges with respect to inviting users to a private channel by sending them remote notifications to join the channel. We searched through the documents however, we do not seem to get a handle to a document that would point us to a solution for our problem statement.

Steps -

- Request for token with the device UUID
- Create an instance of IPMessagingClient with the newly generated token

  ```
  let accessManager= TwilioAccessManager.init(token: token, delegate: self)  
  let client = TwilioIPMessagingClient.ipMessagingClientWithAccessManager(accessManager, properties: nil, delegate: self)
  ```
- Call registerWithToken on the instance of IPMessagingClient

  ```
  ipMessagingClient.registerWithToken(deviceToken)
  ```
- If the user wants to chat with another user

  - we check if the private channel exists

    ```
    let availableChannel = channels?.channelWithUniqueName(defaultChannel)
    ```
  - if the channel exists, we let the logged-in user join the channel

    ```
    availableChannel.joinWithCompletion({ (result) in
                    if result.isSuccessful(){ ... }})
    ```
  - if the channel does not exist then we create the new private channel

    ```
    let options: [NSObject:AnyObject] = [
        TWMChannelOptionFriendlyName: defaultChannel,
        TWMChannelOptionUniqueName: defaultChannel,
        TWMChannelOptionType: TWMChannelType.Private.rawValue
    ]  

    channels?.createChannelWithOptions(options, completion: { (result, channel) in
            if result.isSuccessful(){
                channel.joinWithCompletion({ (result) in
                    if result.isSuccessful(){ ... }})
    ```
  - Once, the user joins the channel successfully, we send invite to the other user to join the same channel.

    ```
    availableChannel.members.inviteByIdentity(other_user_name, completion: { 
        (result) in
            if result.isSuccessful(){ ... })
    ```
  - We then wait for the didReceiveRemoteNotification, available in the AppDelegate to fire. within which we have a piece of code to show the notification through badge or message or sound. `<- problem Statement`

This is where the problem arises, the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` does not fire at all.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps to set up to [receive push notifications from IP Messaging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/push-notifications-ios)? Are you able to receive push notifications for other events, like a user receiving a new message?

Comment: Hey Philnash, Yes, i followed the same document for writing my push notification. Also, i first created apple push certificate for production, however, later i added another one for the development, yet, it didn't work. Also, i tried sending a message to the user, however, that too does not fire the didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You need to [make sure you have notifications enabled for the IP Messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/push-notification-configuration) you are using.

Currently you need to do this using the REST API, though support for this will come to the [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/ip-messaging/dashboard) soon.

In the meantime, here's an example of how you would enable push notifications for channel invites and new messages:

```
curl -X POST https://ip-messaging.twilio.com/v1/Services/{service sid} \
 -d 'Notifications.NewMessage.Enabled=true' \
 -d 'Notifications.NewMessage.Template=A New message in ${CHANNEL} from ${USER}: ${MESSAGE}' \
 -d 'Notifications.InvitedToChannel.Enabled=true' \
 -d 'Notifications.InvitedToChannel.Template=${USER} has invited you to join the channel ${CHANNEL}' \
 -u '{twilio account sid}:{twilio auth token}'
```

Just substitute your Account SID, Auth Token and Messaging Service SID in the above. Check out all the details on the [types of notification you can enable and notification templates in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/push-notification-configuration).

Comment: you made my day!! Thanks a ton. It worked like a charm.